# Grouped Citation problem in Elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle, cite-package

I am getting the error `Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.` with `elsearticle` class. I am trying to shorten references of type `[1,2,3,4,5]` to `[1-5]` using the `cite` package but I got the above error.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc}
\volume{00}
\firstpage{1}
\journalname{UVW}
\runauth{}
\jid{procs}
\jnltitlelogo{Procedia Computer Science}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newcommand{\argmin}[1]{\underset{#1}{\operatorname{argmin}} }
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}


\dochead{}

\title{XYZ }% and   Application to Anomaly Detection }

% use optional labels to link authors explicitly to addresses:
\author[label1]{Chandresh Kumar Maurya, Durga Toshniwal }
 %\author[label1]{ }
 \author[label2]{Gopalan Vijendran Venkoparao}
 \address[label1]{Department of Computer Science \& Engineering, Indian
      Institute of Technology, Roorkee-247667, Haridwar, U.K., India}
% \address[label2]{Department of Computer Science \& Engineering, Indian
%     Institute of Technology, Roorkee-247667, Haridwar, U.K., India}
 \address[label2]{Research \& Technology Center, RBEI, Bangalore}


\begin{abstract}
xyz
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
ABX
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
 \cite{Shuo:2015,ckm2015,Akbani04applyingsupport,He2009,Chawla2002,Liu2006}. It 
 aims to 

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{./TKDE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `cite`  and `natbib`  are incompatible => `cite` and `elsarticle` are incompatible.

Comment: Add `compress` to the documentclass options, right behind `times`. Don't forget the comma.

Comment: @Johannes_B. Second trick worked like a charm. Thanks!.

Comment: With `compress` i get `[1-5]`. What do you want exactly?

Comment: The same what you have got.